# How get value from POST

Tags: php

This piece of code has been tripping me out for the past four hours. It is deleting a row of photos by the primary ID.

I have `var_dump($selectedPhoto)` and it is the correct ID, a number. My code will run every time I press delete photo, get to the `mysqli_stmt_store_result` part and shoots out the `$txtMessage`, **But the database does not update.**

This is really weird because I have used the exact same code, with different variables on another page and it works perfectly fine.

Can you see any errors by looking at this? OR have a better way to writing the delete statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['btnDeletePhoto']))
{
    $selectedPhoto = $_SESSION['selectedPhoto'];
    $deleteString = "DELETE FROM Photos WHERE PhotoID = ?";
    $preparedDeleteStmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $deleteString);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($preparedDeleteStmt, 'i', $selectedPhoto);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($preparedDeleteStmt))
    {
        mysqli_close($link);
        die("The system is not available, try again later");
    }
    if(mysqli_stmt_store_result($preparedDeleteStmt))
    {
        $txtMessage = "Delete successfull";
    }
```

To add: `$selectedPhoto` is a value of a select, drop down list value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the photo comes from the value of a select, it is not going to be stored in a session variable, so you probably need to change:

```
$selectedPhoto = $_SESSION['selectedPhoto'];
```

to:

```
$selectedPhoto = $_POST['selectedPhoto'];
```

Apart from that you need to add error handling to all database operations.

Comment: Yes, because of it not being able to work, I have gone through the trouble of saving the `$_POST` to a session